# Skip OAuth user approval in Spring Boot OAuth2

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I just want to know if there is any way to skip User approval screen in Spring Boot - Spring Security OAuth2. I heard about custom user approval handler but I am quite not sure how to override it to disable user approval process and do a direct redirect.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why? I have this form returned to my /authorize request, I think to disable it but I wonder if it's the safe and good solution!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need a custom handler to skip approval (since 2.0 anyway). You just set the `autoApprove` flag in the client details to "true" (or a list of scope patterns to auto approve).

Comment: Just to make sure this is extra clear, notice @Dave Syer has put true in quotations. If you're storing your client details in a database, this value needs be a string in the database, not the boolean value for true.

Comment: That’s precisely when it works. Not sure what you could mean.

Comment: What he means is, if you are storing client details in the DB, you need to save the autoapprove column value as 'true'  (string) and not as 1 (mysql default value for a true boolean, for example)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I changed it in my JHipster application:

```java
        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(jhipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getClientid())
                .autoApprove(true)
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorities(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .secret(jhipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getSecret())
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(jhipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getTokenValidityInSeconds());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

set property **auto-approve-scopes: '.*'** in application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: acme
      client-secret: acmesecret
      scope: read,write
      auto-approve-scopes: '.*'
```

seee also https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver

Answer (score 0):

For the newer `spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server`, the configuration would be as follows:

```java
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    final RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
         // other settings...
         .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
        .build()
    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
}
```